# Setting datetime manually (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

So I am trying to set the percurso_time attribute for @button_finish_div manually in my controller on the update method. Basically if the value for the percurso attibute is false before if gets updated and true afterwards, I want to set percurso_time to the current datetime. However, even though my code runs with no errors, when I check the values on the rails console I find if that percurso_time is still nil. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
def update
  before_percurso = @button_finish_div.percurso

  if @button_finish_div.update(button_finish_div_params)

    after_percurso = @button_finish_div.percurso

    if before_percurso == false && after_percurso == true
      @button_finish_div.percurso_time = DateTime.now
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: add this `@button_finish_div.save` after this `@button_finish_div.percurso_time = DateTime.now`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just assign the value to it, you need to save it after assignment like
`@button_finish_div.save`

Or you can use `update_attribute` or `update_column` to update it.